# How can I have authenticated WordPress users automatically sign into Moodle?

Tags: authentication

Okay, so here's the deal. I'm looking for a way to log people into Moodle using their WordPress credentials, with this kind of workflow:

User "bbarker" is logged into WordPress. He clicks a link that will bring him to a particular page within Moodle, one which requires authentication. WordPress *automatically* looks for a "bbarker" user within Moodle, and if a match exists, it logs him in behind the scenes. From the user's perspective, he appears within Moodle, automatically logged in as himself, without entering anything.

I'm hoping there exists a solution that makes use of a plugin for most of the functionality, but realistically, I expect some development will be needed.

Comment: It appears Moodle can use an "external database" for authentication purposes -- https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Authentication . I suspect that you'd need to somehow convince Moodle to use WordPress's cookie, though, to do what you're asking. Using WP's database to authenticate would still require your users to log in to Moodle separately -- though you'd be able to use the same username/password pair for both.

Comment: As it is now this is essentially a moodle question, not a wordpress one. We can help you to figure out the wordpress side but can't help you write the code that will automatically login users into moodle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the WordPress part is concerned, you'll need to write a plugin which creates a widget or otherwise inserts a link onto your WordPress site. The following assumes you are familiar with plugin development.

Generate the link by using a wp_nonce_url to help ensure the WordPress user is the one who clicked the link.

See:
- [WordPress Nonces « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)

When the user clicks the link, it should submit the appropriate user data needed. For example, if the user login is the same on both WordPress and moodle then you will want to get user_login.

See:
- [Function Reference/get userdata « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

It is possible to generate a url with a login authentication token. I'm not familiar with doing so via moodle API, and this is beyond the scope of this StackExchange network, so you'll have to ask a specific question for that elsewhere.

That said, here is one general method example:
- [Passwordless authentication: Secure, simple, and fast to deploy ✩
        Mozilla Hacks – the Web developer blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/10/passwordless-authentication-secure-simple-and-fast-to-deploy/)

Back to the WordPress related scripting. Make sure your plugin adds the moodle host in a allowed_redirect_hosts filter.

See:
 - [Plugin API/Filter Reference/allowed redirect hosts « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/allowed_redirect_hosts)

Your script should use a wp_safe_redirect at this point to redirect the WordPress user to the new login authentication url.

See:
 - [Function Reference/wp safe redirect « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect)

Assuming you solve the moodle authentication issue, this should give you a general idea of what can be done to solve the WordPress side of the problem.

**Update:** There is an "external database authentication" plugin for moodle which seems ideal for this. Again, it's beyond the scope of this site, but learn how to use it and you should be set.

> This method uses an external database table to check whether a given
>   username and password is valid. If the user does not currently exist
>   in Moodle a new account will be created and their information copied
>   from the external database.

See:
 - [External database authentication - MoodleDocs](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/External_database_authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin which provides end users with an option to enter a single username and password on the WordPress website and gain access on WordPress as well as Moodle simultaneously
https://edwiser.org/bridge/extensions/single-sign-on/

Comment: Does this plugin also works with moodlerooms?